# How to get all regex matches from substrings only with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get all hex colors from styles attributes in html, but not another hex color values.
Really it is a common task I want to understand so I don't want to get other solution, regex only.
In other words I need to get substrings with a regex pattern (hex color in this case) from a substring limited by know start and end patterns (style="substring to get values here")

My pattern

```
(?<=style=").*(#[A-F0-9]{6}).*(?=")
```

My test html:

```
<span style="color: #FF0000;background-color: #FFFF99;font-family: Calibri;font-size: 11pt;font-weight: bold;font-style: normal">This shouldn't be in result #FFFF99</span>
<span style="color: #FF0000;background-color: #FFFF99;font-family: Calibri;font-size: 11pt;font-weight: bold;font-style: normal">This shouldn't be in result #FFFF99</span>
```

I can get only last entry with this pattern, but I need to get all. (so in my example I should get 4 color values: 2 from first span and 2 from second one). How can I achieve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this? `(?<=style="[^"]*)#[A-F0-9]{6}\b(?=[^"]*")` https://regex101.com/r/Plbirg/1

Comment: Are you using javascript?

Comment: Yes, like this! But I wonder what happening here?

Comment: If you really want to understand. Get familiar with Chomsky. And that HTML has a context free grammar. And why you cannot parse it with only regex.

Comment: Oh and if Chomsky is too dry and inapplicable computer science to your taste. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/383793)

Comment: Just be cautious that non-fixed width [lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) has limited support, your code will fail to compile on IE, iOS devices and Safari.

Comment: Chomsky is interesting, but my question means it could be not only html. This is regarding search with patterns in substrings with reges and html just as example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a quantifier in a positive lookahead [is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind):

```
(?<=\bstyle="[^"]*)#[A-F0-9]{6}\b(?=[^"]*")
```

- `(?<=\bstyle="[^"]*)` Positive lookbehind, assert `style="` followed by 0+ occurrences of any char except `"` to the left
- `#[A-F0-9]{6}\b` Match `#` and 6 times any of the listed chars followed by a word boundary to prevent an empty match
- `(?=[^"]*")` Positive lookahead, assert a 0+ times any char except `"` and then match a `"` at the right.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kbOB71/1)

**Note** that this matches the word `style` and is not bounded to an element.

There are brittle ways to match brackets, but this can easily break.

```
(?<=<[^<>]*\bstyle="[^"]*)#[A-F0-9]{6}\b(?=[^"<>]*"[^<>]*>)
```

Comment: THanks for the answer, but why I can't use just .* instead of [^"] ? I tried it but regex101 tell me it is wrong pattern

Comment: @AndreyKucher Because `.*` also matches `"` and will cross the `"` boundary and will match too much.